# List style type only when hovering over list item.

Tags: html, css

How can I make the list-style-type: square; only appear when I hover over one of the list items?

To be clear I want list-style-type: none; unless I'm hovering over one of the list items.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/Ut25k/)

HTML

```
<ul>
    <li>Item</li>
</ul>
```

CSS

```
li{
    list-style-type:none;
}
li:hover{
    list-style-type:square;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
    li{
        list-style-type:none;
    }
    li:hover{
        list-style-type:square;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

you could try

```
li { list-style-type: none; }
li:hover { list-style-type: square; }
```