# Border around list item, including including list style type

Tags: html, css

When I hover a list item, I want a border around the entire area including the list-style-type:square; At the moment my border can only encompass the text in the list item...

Thanks for the help.

Comment: aren't you repeating questions??? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20240863/list-style-type-only-when-hovering-over-list-item

Comment: @Mayank Not exactly, the questions are not the same thing.

Comment: Can you post some code, because, at the moment, we can't really help you?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Bring the bullet inside the list item with `list-style-position`:

```
ul li{
    padding-left:3px;
    list-style-position:inside;
    border:1px solid transparent;
}
ul li:hover{
    border-color:#F00;
}
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/oGeez/B43wu/)

Answer (score 0):

```
li:hover { border: 2px solid blue; 
           list-style-type: square;
           list-style-position: inside; }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
li:hover{
    border:1px solid grey;
    list-style-position:inside;
}
```

**[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/S8R6j/)**

[Updated Fiddle...](http://jsfiddle.net/S8R6j/1/)

Answer (score 0):

Border with list style type

```
ul li{list-style-position:inside;border:2px solid red;}
```

Border without list style type

```
ul li{list-style-position:outside;border:2px solid red;}
```